# Automate load of csv data in ms access, and include autonumer primary key ID field

Tags: sql, csv, ms-access, vba

I am having trouble adding a primary key autonumber ID field to a ms access table which I have loaded using the `DoCmd.transfertext` script. I have tried a sql script and even doing it manually but I get the following error: "File sharing lock count exceeded. Increase MaxLocksPerFile registry entry".

I have tried countering this using `DAO.DBEngine.SetOption dbmaxlocksperfile,1500000`, but then I get another bug saying I have reached the memory limit, note the data set has 900 000 rows.

The funny thing is if I manually load the file using the text import wizard, I can set the wizard to add the primary key ID field, and it works perfectly fine. I know the `DoCmd.TransferText` doesn't allow the addition of an autonumber primary key field, so I am wondering how best to load my data with the autonumber ID field?

See my code below:

```vb
Function Data_Load()
Dim strSQL

DoCmd.TransferText acImportDelim, "xxx Import   Specification", "xxx", "C:\xxx.csv", True

DAO.DBEngine.SetOption dbMaxLocksPerFile, 1500000
strSQL = "ALTER TABLE PDQ ADD COLUMN ID AUTOINCREMENT"
Set rs = CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef("strSQL")
DoCmd.RunSQL (strSQL)

DAO.DBEngine.SetOption dbMaxLocksPerFile, 9500    

End Function
```

Comment: Since the import wizard can do this (and it works), it might be worth a try to save a manual import, and run it with [`DoCmd.RunSavedImportExport`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/access-vba/articles/docmd-runsavedimportexport-method-access). You may have to add workarounds to make sure the import source and target are always identical.

Comment: I just tested it, and this works fine. :) I added some ideas for workarounds in my answer.

Comment: In case the primary key already exists in table and also defined in csv file. What should happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the import wizard can do this (and it works), use it!

One-time preparations:

- Copy a sample import file to a generic location from where all saved imports will be run
- Do a manual import into table "myTable", and save it at the end as e.g. "myTable_Import".

Then you can run it with [`DoCmd.RunSavedImportExport`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/access-vba/articles/docmd-runsavedimportexport-method-access) :

```vb
Sub TestSavedImport()

    On Error Resume Next
    DoCmd.DeleteObject acTable, "myTable"
    On Error GoTo 0

    ' copy your actual import file to the generic path\file 
    ' that you used during the manual import
    ' ...

    ' run saved import
    DoCmd.RunSavedImportExport "myTable_Import"

    ' rename to actual target name
    DoCmd.Rename "RealTableName", acTable, "myTable"

End Sub
```